# What exactly does the "count" mean in the call tree in memory allocations in instruments?

Tags: ios, profiling, instruments

I want to know what exactly does the "count" mean in the call tree in memory allocations in instruments. I have tried watching videos but they just won't tell.
[image of count in the call tree in instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPK2t.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of calls to allocate memory in this function and all of the functions it calls (it's cumulative).